# Python dill a dynamic class object inside a module and read it in a new python session

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, metaclass, dill

Say I have 2 submodulew inside a package as

```
|-packageA
   |- moduleA
   |- moduleB
```

moduleB has a dynamic class creation method that uses type() to create new class.

```
def moduleB.fun():
   new_cls = type("bar",(obejct,),{})
   return new_cls
```

The class created is always of the namesapce `packageA.moduleB.bar`. (Instead I need it to be just `bar`.)

When I dill an object created from this dynamic class, it dumps it along with the namespace name.

```
def moduleA.fun2():
  new_cls = moduleB.fun()
  obj = new_cls("Object of new class")
  dill.dump(obj, open("test.obj","wb"))
```

The problem comes when I am in a new python session and trying to load this dill file.

In a new session,

```
dat = dill.load(open("test.obj","rb"))
```

The dill complains that `Can't get attribute 'bar' on <module 'packageA.moduleB'>`

I tried setting it to `global()["bar"] = new_cls` in moduleB.fun(), but it is the type creation that seems to be a problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well - looks like dill has 2 class pickling behaviors - in one of then, it tries to bind the class to its declaration in the originating module, and on the other one, it switches to a visible `create_type` operand inside the Pickle bytestring itself.

I could switch to the second module by overwriting the class'`__module__` attribute with `"__main__"` before pickling - so, give this a try:

```
def moduleA.fun2():
  new_cls = moduleB.fun()
  new_cls.__module__ = "__main__"
  new_cls.__qualname__ = new_cls.__name__.split(".")[-1]
  obj = new_cls("Object of new class")
  dill.dump(obj, open("test.obj","wb"))
```